# combine three query and get specific error alert

Tags: php, mysql

how can i brief this queries?
i want to combine them but get specific error alert and different three variable

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT content FROM post where title='tv'";
    $sql2 = "SELECT content FROM post where title='radio'";
    $sql3 = "SELECT content FROM post where title='net'";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $result2 = $connection->query($sql2);
    $result3 = $connection->query($sql3);
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $tvPrice = $row['content']; 
        }
    }else{
        echo "tv error";
    }
    if ($result2->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result2->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $radioPrice = $row['content']; 
        }
    }else{
        echo "radio error";
    }
    if ($result3->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result3->fetch_assoc()) { 
            $netPrice = $row['content']; 
        }
    }else{
        echo "net error";
    }
?>
```

Comment: running multiple lines of code together into one line does not speed up execution or interpretation. It does however make the code much more difficult to read and therefore debug and maintain

Comment: _NOTE_ If a query returns only one row, then you dont need the while loop! If the query can return more than one row then `$netPrice = $row['content'];` within that loop will just overwrite the variable multiple time and you will see only the last value you set it to

Comment: `SELECT content FROM post WHERE title IN('tv', 'radio', 'net')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `IN()` you can return only those rows with a title of 'tv', 'radio' and 'net'. Then add the `title` to the query selection so you know which results a re which.

Then just amend you code to fetch all the results into a rows array and then check for the entries and report errors accordingly

```
<?php
// make a connection to the database obviously :)
$sql = "SELECT title, content 
        FROM post 
        WHERE title IN('tv', 'radio', 'net')";
$result = $connection->query($sql);
$rows = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// better initialise the variables in case you try using them later
$tvPrice = $radioPrice = $netPrice = 0;

foreach ($rows as $row){
    if ($row['title'] == 'tv')){
        $tvPrice = $row['content']; 
    }
    
    if ($row['title'] == 'radio') {
        $radioPrice = $row['content']; 
    }

    if ($row['title'] == 'net') {
        $netPrice = $row['content']; 
    }
}
if ( $tvPrice == 0 ) echo 'tv error';
if ( $radioPrice == 0 ) echo 'radio error';
if ( $netPrice == 0 ) echo 'net error';
?>
```

Comment: i can't edit this answer but it work well with few changes. fetch_all() should be fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC) and extra parentheses in if condition should be remove.

Answer (score -1):

Usually you don't actually need tree (or more) variables; use an array.

```
<?php

$titles = ['tv', 'radio', 'net'];

// Generate the query
$sql = 
    "SELECT content, title FROM post WHERE title IN(" 
        . implode(", ", array_map(function( $title ) use( $connection ) {
            return '"' . mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $title) . '"';
        }, $titles) ) 
    . ")";

$result = $connection->query($sql);

$prices = [];

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            
        // Check for duplicates
        if( !empty( $prices[ $row['title'] . 'Price' ] ) )
            echo $row['title'] . " has duplicate error";
        else
            $prices[ $row['title'] . 'Price' ] = $row['content'];
    }
}

// Check if we have all desires rows 
foreach( $titles as $title )
    if( empty( $prices[ $title . 'Price' ] ) )
        echo "$title missing error";

// If you really need tree variables instead of array:
extract($prices);
```